# Photoshop - Justify tool for text

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

In MS Word, justify tool works great. It gives nice spacing between latter and words but it doesn't work well in Photoshop. As you can see in image.

[image]

How to make it work like in MS-Word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Paragraph > then Check Adobe-Every-Line Composer..[image: Follow Image]

Comment: I am using Adobe CS6 and I can't find this option. Only `Every-Line Composer` is available.

Comment: I checked it but it isn't working :(

Comment: I haven't tried CS6, I think it's the same. Did you try it?

Comment: Nice! So, it does the same? :D